# Update the password value only when i change the password or else it retain the same value

Tags: php, passwords, laravel-5.4

I am trying to change the password value by getting old password it working fine but what my problem is when i try to update my field it save the new password value as empty(because i leave this field empty) i want to  update the new password only when i change the new password value or else it maintain the current password in the new password field

here is inside my controller

```
   public function profileupdate(Request $request,$id)
    {
    if(Auth::Check())
    {

        $request_data = $request->All();
        $validator = $this->validator($request_data);
        if($validator->fails())
        {
         $this->throwValidationException($request, $validator); 
        }

    else
    {  
      $current_password = Auth::User()->password;   
      if(Hash::check($request_data['current-password'], $current_password))
      {
        $user_id = Auth::User()->id;                       
        $admin = Admin::find($user_id);        
        $admin->update([
            'name'=>$request['name'],
            'job_title'=> $request['job_title'],
            'email'=>$request['email'],
            'phone_number'=>$request['phone_number'],
            'password'=> Hash::make($request['password']),
        ]);
        return  redirect('/admin/profile')
           ->with('message', 'Admin Profile updated successfuly!');
      }
      else
      { 
          return  redirect('/admin/profile')
        ->with('password', 'Please enter correct password!'); 
      }
    }        
  }
  else
  {
    return redirect()->to('/');
  }    
}
```

Inside my view

```
  <div class="control-group{{ $errors->has('current-password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label class="control-label"> Current Password:</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                               <input type="password" class="form-control" id="current-password" name="current-password" placeholder="Password">
                              @if(Session::has('password')) <span class="help-inline"> <strong>{{Session::get('password')}} </strong></span> @endif
                              @if ($errors->has('current-password'))
                                                <span class="help-inline">
                                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('current-password') }}</strong>
                                                </span>
                             @endif
                            </div>
                    </div>
                     <div class="control-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label class="control-label"> New Password:</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                               <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                              @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                                <span class="help-inline">
                                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                                </span>
                             @endif
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group{{ $errors->has('password_confirmation') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                              <label class="control-label">Confirm Password:</label>
                              <div class="controls">
                                 <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password_confirmation" name="password_confirmation" placeholder="Re-enter Password">
                                 @if ($errors->has('password_confirmation'))
                                                <span class="help-inline">
                                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password_confirmation') }}</strong>
                                                </span>
                             @endif
                              </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: where are the validation rules ? it should not pass if it's empty, also try `var_dump` the request to see the fields and their values .

Answer (score 0):

Simply build the array which updates the values dynamically instead of statically. The majority of the array is still static, but the password is now dynamically added, depending of there was a value passed to the `password` field in your form.

```
// Values which are always updated
$update_values = [
    'name'=>$request['name'],
    'job_title'=> $request['job_title'],
    'email'=>$request['email'],
    'phone_number'=>$request['phone_number']
];
// If the password-field isn't empty, we add it to the values that are updated
if (!empty($request['password']))
    $update_values['password'] = Hash::make($request['password']);

// Execute the update
$admin->update($update_values);
```